# What's the appropiate method to store values from fragments?

Tags: android, database, android-activity, android-fragments

I'm new to android and fragments, so my question is this about the appropriate method to store values in the app database.

Calling a fragment from activity and passing the database handler?

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment);
fragment.<specific_function_name>(dbhandler);
```

or calling an activity method from the fragment?

```
import mainActivity;
...
mainActivity currentActivity=(mainActivity )getActivity();
currentActivity.storeValures(val,val2...)
```

or just setting a database handler on every fragment?...

Or maybe there is a better design to deal with this?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I would say calling activity methods from fragments if the database calls are similar, that is to avoid redundant code. Or better yet, have a separate class handle database calls and hand a reference to that class to the fragments such that database activity is completely detached from both Activities and Fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since database manager will be universal for the entire app, you can create a DataHandler class, that will have singleton Datahandler instance

```
public class MyDatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static MyDatabaseHandler databaseHandlerInstance; 

    public static synchronized MyDatabaseHandler getInstance(Context context) {
      if(databaseHandlerInstance ==  null)
         databaseHandlerInstance = new MyDatabaseHandler(Context context);

      return databaseHandlerInstance;
    } 

    public MyDatabaseHandler(Context context){
        // Call to super class
        //
    }

   // ..... onCreate calls
}
```

This way you can use dbhandler from anywhere in your app like MyDatabaseHandler.getInstance(context)

I use this approach ...

Comment: I think I'll use this, but what should do i do if i need to pass a Context to my databaseHandler constructor/getInstance? like     public databaseConnection(Context context) {
      super(context, databaseName, null, DATABASE_VERSION);}

Comment: Suppose u have dbHandler for different tables you can define and initialize each one of them in the constructor DatabaseHandler and use them, you can pass context and other needed params as parameters of constructor

Comment: I think im a little bit confused as im new to android. So, i can use a handler from my activity with new databaseConnection(this) as the activity includes the context. BUT, from the fragment this is not possible or I'd have to do new databaseConnection(getActivity());. is this ok?. I cant get a usable handler from the fragment if isnt initialized, and it wont initialize without context. Thanks

Comment: Yeah u can use getActivity() from fragment

Comment: If you dont want to pass context each time you can use applicationContext which you can get easily if you are overriding application class